# PowerShell Reports a Parsing Error, but Doesn’t Give a Code Location

Tags: powershell

The following error message appears in my Visual Studio Code (VSC) console immediately after my script starts, before reaching the debug break point on the first line of code:

```
ParserError: Missing statement block after if ( condition ).
```

However, it doesn’t identify the code location that has the error, and the script continues to run.

How do I tell where the error is?

$psVersionTable output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Ok. I eventually found the problem, but only after searching for **all** occurrences of the word “if” in my code base. I couldn’t see that VSC had given any indication of a problem other than a small red squiggle inside the offending code. There nothing in the folder list I could find that showed where the problem was. Am I missing some key functionality of VSC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact position of the preceding token is actually part of the exception, VSCode just isn't surfacing it.

For future reference, you can find out by reproducing and catching the exception, like so:

```
try {
  # try to execute the script
  .\path\to\broken_script.ps1
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ParseException] {
  # iterate over any parser errors and output their starting location
  foreach ($parseError in $_.Exception.Errors){
    Write-Host $parseError.Message -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host (' at line {0}, column {1}' -f $parseError.Extent.StartLineNumber,$parseError.Extent.StartColumnNumber) -ForegroundColor Red
  }
}
```

---

If you don't want to attempt execution of the script, you can also invoke the parsing routine manually:

```
$scriptPath = 'path\to\script.ps1'
$parseErrors = @()
$null = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile((Convert-Path $scriptPath), [ref]$null, [ref]$parseErrors)

foreach ($parseError in $parseErrors){
  Write-Host $parseError.Message -ForegroundColor Red
  Write-Host (' at line {0}, column {1}' -f $parseError.Extent.StartLineNumber,$parseError.Extent.StartColumnNumber) -ForegroundColor Red
}
```